# Revel App accessible in browser, returns 502 when hit in terminal via curl

Tags: curl, nginx, go, revel

The Revel site I'm working on works fine in the browser, but when hit it in the terminal via a curl, it returns a 502. Checking the error log for Revel, it throws a long panic error when hit by curl, starting like...

> {"caller":"panic.go:35","error":"runtime error: index out of
>   range","lvl":"eror","module":"revel","msg":"PanicFilter: Caught panic,
>   unable to determine stack
>   location","section":"util","stack":"goroutine 265...

When I access the site via the browser, no new error appears. Nginx is throwing the following error...

> 22393#22393: *5098 upstream prematurely closed connection while
>   reading response header from upstream

My nginx config looks essentially like...

```
server {

    server_name name-of-site.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
}
```

At first I thought this was an issue with my Nginx config, but seeing I'm getting an error thrown by Go/Revel when I hit the site via curl request, I'm wondering if it's an issue with Go or Revel? Anyone had similar issues when getting a Go site running through Nginx? Thanks in advance, any direction would be useful.

Comment: "I'm wondering if it's an issue with Go or Revel?" there is an easy way to find out, don't use revel and stick to net/http

Comment: The error is `runtime error: index out of range`; the curl command is probably not sending some header or body that you're expecting, but we can't really help you with that since we don't see your code ;-) There is a stack trace in the error message which should be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, wasn't sure if this was a Nginx config error or an error with the code itself. Ended up being the code. To debug, ran `revel run my.app` on the server instead of `revel build my.app /Server/ prod`, which allowed me to look at the Revel logs. Don't know why I didn't think of this before. And you're right @MartinTournoij, it was an issue with headers being expected in the code.